# Asp.net Mvc Routing problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

---

[alt text http://img243.imageshack.us/img243/3249/50263677.jpg](http://img243.imageshack.us/img243/3249/50263677.jpg)

**Global.asax Code:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "article", action = "article", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I want to use url routing like this:

www.domainname.com/Article/123/bla_article

how can ı do this ?

This work: www.domainname.com/article/article/123

this not work: www.domainname.com/article/123

please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "Article", 
    "Article/{id}", 
    new { controller = "article", action = "article", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"article/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { action = "article", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: This route would still be : /article/article/123